NGinX allow only one user from .htpasswd
i have 2 folders: /protected and /admin
inside the htpasswd i have multiple users and the one named "admin"
how do i setup so that all the users with admin can access the /protected folder but only admin can access the /admin folder?
location /protected {
    auth_basic "Protected Area";
    auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;

    root /static;
    autoindex_exact_size off;
    autoindex on;
}

location /admin {
    auth_basic "Restricted Area";
    auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;

    set $is_admin 0;

    if ($remote_user = "admin") {
      set $is_admin 1;
    }

    if ($is_admin = 0) {
      return 403;
    }

    root /static;
    autoindex_exact_size off;
    autoindex on;
}

location / {
    root /static;
    autoindex_exact_size off;
    autoindex on;
}


You could try following approach:
In server context, add following:
map $remote_user $htpasswd_path {
    admin .htpasswd;
    default /dev/null;
}

And then in server context:
auth_basic_user_file $htpasswd_path;

With this configuration one should be able to choose different files based on username.

It worked, thank you so much!
